# Only enabling a user to change an integer input via click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, integer, simple-form

I have an integer input using simple form and I wan't to stop a user from being able to type inside the input. I only want them to change the input value by clicking on the arrow on the right side of the input.

Is there a way to do this without javascript, or simple javascript if there is not.
Using readonly and disabled attributes does not work as it stops the user from being able to use the arrows.

`<%= f.input :quantity, as: :integer %>`

[image]

Comment: That does not seem very accessible. Why would you want that?

Answer (score 0):

The way this is done is to have a div and make it appear to be an input by css styling.

Also with css, insert the up/down arrows. Looks as if you've done this already.

Then with javascript you can increment/decrement the value of a hidden input, in response to clicking on the up/down arrows, and also put the current value in the div that *appears* to be a real input.